# Android app stops working if rotated during post submission

Tags: bug, android-app

I have **Stack Exchange** app version **1.0.83** (observed before on 1.0.62).

My mobile is Micromax Canvas Spark and Android version is 5.0 Lollipop.

There is a problem with the application. It stops working if the device is rotated from portrait to landscape when a post is being submitted.

Steps to reproduce: Write anything on the title and body, then click the preview button and rotate your mobile phone.

The app is fantastic otherwise. Is it a problem with the app or with my android?

Comment: Please upgrade.

Comment: @DeerHunter I upgraded to 1.0.83 but still the problem is there but there were 2 buttons on the dialog box this time namely "Report" and "OK".

Comment: @DeerHunter Try it out yourself. Write anything on the title and body, then click the preview button and rotate your mobile phone.

Comment: Works fine for me. What are the make and model of your phone?

Comment: @DeerHunter My mobile is Micromax Canvas Spark and Android version is 5.0 Lollipop.

Comment: Aman, I took the liberty to update your question with relevant details. Feel free to edit it further to better reflect your case.

Comment: @DeerHunter Thank you.

Comment: Same problem for me using 1.0.83 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Marshmallow. While doing any kind of editing, whether posting comments or answers, rotating the screen does not crash the app, but does cause the Post button to stop working. I copy what I typed, back out a couple of screens and come back to where I was, paste, and then Post works as long as I don't rotate again.